How do I check a related object record within a Flow?
I have a use case within a record triggered flow where I need to check if an Opportunity that triggered the flow has a record created within a related (master-detail relationship) Object before continuing the flow?
If it doesn't have the record in place, it ends the flow. It doesn't look like I can drill from Opportunity into a detail object to get a record id so I'm stuck...

No, you will have to do a Get Records action on the child records and make your decision from the results.

100% but I can't seem to figure out how to map the id of the child record within the GET element...

Please [edit] your post to describe the related object and include screenshots of your flow steps.  You should be able to Get Records on all the child records related to parent opportunity.

I figured it out. Since you can't lookup from master to detail, you have to grab the name field located on the detail that associated with the master/detail relationship and use the id of the master object in the GET Element

Ok, you can post that as an Answer and mark your question as answered.

Since you can't lookup from master to detail, you have to grab the name field located on the detail that associated with the master/detail relationship and use the id of the master object in the GET Element
